# How to create a proper positioning of user profile links asked to submit in a html document? How to create it by changing codes?

Tags: html

[Here I want to do that the "LinkedIn", "Facebook" and "stackoverflow" all can share same spaces before the url input box.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YziJV.png)

Comment: Please post the code you have so far. It will make it much easier for us to help you

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Subham</title>
</head>
<body>
    https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ol2sQ.jpg?s=256&g=1
    
</body>
</html>

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.